# Conditional MySQL INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, conditional-statements

I develop this solution, if any else have a better solution please share.

```
SET @num = (SELECT count(distinct(detalle)) as 'distintos'
FROM
(SELECT detalle, SUBSTRING(momento, 1, 10) as momento FROM t2
where detalle in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I')) AS T1
where momento like (Select SUBSTRING(momento, 1, 10) as momento from t2 order by momento desc limit 1));

INSERT INTO `t2`.`log_reportes` (`accion`, `detalle`)
SELECT 'REVISION AUTOMATICA', 'ERROR' FROM DUAL
WHERE @num = 6;

INSERT INTO `t2`.`log_reportes` (`accion`, `detalle`)
SELECT 'REVISION AUTOMATICA', 'OK' FROM DUAL
WHERE @num = 7;
```

Comment: A better solution for what? You haven't told us what you're trying to do.

Comment: There's almost always a better solution than lots of mysterious variables like `@num`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in a single `INSERT` query.

```
INSERT INTO `t2`.`log_reportes` (`accion`, `detalle`)
SELECT 'REVISION AUTOMATICA', IF(distintos = 6, 'ERROR', 'OK')
FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT detalle) as distintos
        FROM (SELECT detalle, SUBSTRING(momento, 1, 10) as momento FROM t2
              where detalle in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I')) AS T1
        where momento = (Select MAX(SUBSTRING(momento, 1, 10)) from t2)
    ) AS t3
WHERE distintos IN (6, 7)
```

I've also simplified the subquery

```
(Select SUBSTRING(momento, 1, 10) as momento from t2 order by momento desc limit 1)
```

into just

```
(Select MAX(SUBSTRING(momento, 1, 10)) from t2)
```

And if `momento` is a `DATETIME`, `SUBSTRING(momento, 1, 10)` is more properly done as `DATE(momento)`.